# Docker does not resolve DNS from BIND server

Tags: ubuntu, bind, docker

I'm trying to use a docker container as local DNS server for rewriting an existing domain's IP inside a private network.

My setup is that I have a private network with some machines and a router which has an internet accessible public IP. One of these machines is serving some content to the internet under a domain (say example.com) pointing to the public IP, by having a port routed from router to it. The thing is that other machines in the private network also need access to that server. Router however blocks packets originating from inside from accessing the public IP. So I thought I would use [this container](https://github.com/sameersbn/docker-bind) as a local DNS server to overwrite that public IP with the local one.

In summary this is the network:

- Ubuntu machine with IP 192.168.1.6 ~> docker host
- Ubuntu machine with IP 192.168.1.4 ~> host of content for example.com
- other machines with IP range 192.168.1.0/8
- DNS server of all the machines is set to 192.168.1.6

now the BIND is setup using this compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  bind:
    image: sameersbn/bind:latest
    restart: always
    dns: 8.8.8.8
    logging:
      driver: "json-file"
      options:
        max-size: "200k"
        max-file: "10"
    environment:
        - ROOT_PASSWORD=somepass
    ports:
      - 10000:10000
      - 53:53/udp
    volumes:
      - ./data:/data
```

and has this config:

```
acl localclients {
    192.168.0.0/16;
    172.17.0.0/16;
    172.23.0.0/16;
    localhost;
    localnets;
};

options {
    directory "/var/cache/bind";
    dnssec-validation auto;

    auth-nxdomain no;
    listen-on-v6 { any; };
    listen-on {
        any;
        };

    recursion yes;

    allow-query { any; };
    allow-recursion {
        localclients;
        };
    allow-query-cache { localclients; };
}
```

currently looking up domain name on docker's host machine (with IP 192.168.1.6) as well as other machines on the same network (IP 192.168.1.x) works as expected:

```
$ nslookup example.com
Server:     192.168.1.6
Address:    192.168.1.6#53

Name:   example.com
Address: 192.168.1.4
```

but I can't use that in another container:

```
$ docker run --rm busybox nslookup example.com
Server:    192.168.1.6
Address 1: 192.168.1.6 servername

Name:      example.com
Address 1: 188.15.221.88
```

when I force using only the local DNS server I get following output

```
$ docker run --rm --dns 192.168.1.6 busybox nslookup example.com
nslookup: can't resolve 'example.com'
Server:    192.168.1.6
Address 1: 192.168.1.6
```

I'm not sure if this is docker problem or a bind config one.

Comment: Just a note, Don't set the DNS on the Docker Host to 192.168.1.6.  Docker doesn't always work without a DNS server and Docker needs to start up and be able to run the container before the container can resolve DNS.

Comment: Do you have a second server in `/etc/resolv.conf` on the Docker host for it to fall back on?

Comment: I have a second server in resolve.conf of the server, but thats the router and resolves the domain to it's public IP which is undesirable. When I use the `--dns` option, the `resolve.conf` in container has only the 192.168.1.6 but if I dont specify that, the `resolve.conf` looks like the host which contains 192.168.1.6 and 192.168.1.1 (router)

Comment: Ok, so docker will still work when there's no container up then. In the second example, container dns in uncontactable and secondary dns does an outside lookup. So your container can't access the host mapped address/port. Can another container use a mapped port?  `docker run -d -p 8081:8081 busybox nc -lp 8081 -e echo -e "HTTP/1.0 GET /\n\nhi"` then `curl 192.168.1.6:8081`

Comment: @Murmel yes, fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

well this is not an answer but rather a workaround I found, so I will not mark it as answer.

I could not find any solutions for this, maybe this is a docker bug, maybe a (strange) desired functionality. However as I was really in need of finding a solution I used `--add-host` for run command and `extra-hosts` in compose files to overcome the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**"--net=host"-based solution**

One option would be to run the second docker with `--net=host`. Than the `--dns 192.168.1.6` should work, because the second docker has the same network stack like the host.

**"custom bridged network"-based solution**

1. Create a custom docker network of type `bridge` with a fix subnet (this makes it possible to [set static IPs to containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27937185/assign-static-ip-to-docker-container)) :

   ```
   docker network create --subnet=172.18.0.0/24 dns-network
   ```
2. Start the "dns docker container" exposing the DNS port 53 and connecting it to the docker network:

   ```
   docker run --publish 53:53 --net=dns-network --ip 172.18.0.53 sameersbn/bind:latest
   ```
3. Start another docker container and configure `172.18.0.53` as DNS server:

   ```
   docker run --dns=172.18.0.53  --net=dns-network busybox nslookup example.com
   ```

Comment: the second option seems a possibility, I have to find time to try it.